# which file format is smallest when we have the same data?

Tags: file, format

It will be really helpful if any one could suggest the smallest file size data format when we have the same data like Tab Separated File(TSF) or Comma Seperated File (CSV) or plain text file where separated by any specific delimters or any other.

Hope we can zip the files using GZip or 7zip  once the we understood the smallest file format.

Comment: wouldn't they the same? a tab character and a comma are both one character.

Comment: I think SaggingRufus is right, but why don't you just try it?

Comment: @hering That is usually a good starting point!

Comment: I have tried bot the formats and the size of the file is same - Like generated a files with 10 lakh records and size is same for both the formats.   It will be really helpful if you could tell me if any other format available which need to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried JSON, BSON, YAML, Protocol buffer, Avro, XML formats

Yaml is readable like JSON format , but it is consuming huge memory.
XML as obvious that it's also consuming huge memory
Proto Buffer and Avro is better than than CSV & TSV file in terms of size, but data is in non human readable format.
My suggestion is to use JSON , that meets the readability and sizing. Also APIs are available to parse the JSON easily.